# Inverse of a cubic function containing the sine function

Tags: inverse-function

The question I'm trying to solve requires me to get the $f^{-1}(x)$ where
$f(x)= x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x + \sin (\pi x/2)$  , but I don't know to proceed with such problems with higher degrees of x (and the trigonometric functions don't help much either) . Any methods , prerequisites and ideas for intuitive approaches will be appreciated

According to the question I'm solving , $f:R$ to R and $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$ and I have to find out the derivative of $g(x)$ at $x=8$

Comment: It is highly improbable that you can find a nice closed form expression for the inverse. Deriving, you can prove that $f'(x) > 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which implies that there is an inverse function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with this function. For instance, you can use implicit derivative to understand better your function near some specific point.